# Flask. Object is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask

Два файла из папки эскиза(blueprint) проекта на flask.
В первом класс, который возвращает json-объект вида
`{'title1':'12345','title2':'45678','title3':'123415'}`
в файле `views.py` результат, который возвращает класс, возвращается обёрнутый в jsonify. После чего получаю ошибку:

> "error":"{'title1':'12345','title2':'45678','title3':'123415'} is not
>   JSON serializable.

Перепробовал множество различных вариантов, результат, к сожалению, неизменен.
Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

1. **__init__.py**

   ```
   import json
   import jsonify
   import requests
   from lxml import html
   from fake_useragent import FakeUserAgent

   class Parser():
       def __init__(self, *args):
           self.start_urls = []
           for keyword in args:
               self.start_urls.append('https://link/?search&value={}'.format(keyword))

       def __repr__(self):
           results=[]
           for link in self.start_urls:
               r = requests.get(link,timeout=10)
               webpage = html.fromstring(r.content)
               title = webpage.xpath("//h2[@class='title']/a")
               for i in title:
                   #results['title'] +=[i.text]
                   results.append(i.text)
           result = {"title%d" % (i+1): results[i] for i in range(len(results))}
           return json.dumps(result,ensure_ascii=False)
   ```
2. **views.py**

   ```
   from flask import Blueprint,render_template,request,jsonify
   from project.parser import Parser

   ###CONFIG###
   parser_blueprint = Blueprint(
       'parser', __name__,
       template_folder='templates'
   )
   ###CONFIG###

   @parser_blueprint.route('/parser', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def parse_this():
       if request.method == 'POST':
           try:
               value1 = str(request.form.get('search-parser'))
               return jsonify(Parser(value1))
           except Exception as e:
               return jsonify({"error":"{}".format(e)})     
       return render_template('parser.html')
   ```

Comment: Зачем `json.dumps()`? Почему бы не возвращать словарь?

Answer (score 2):

[`jsonsify()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.json.jsonify) передаёт аргумент во [`flask.json.dumps()` функцию](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.json.dumps), которая использует [`flask.json.JSONEncoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder) по умолчанию.

Чтобы поддерживать `Parser` объекты, добавьте `Parser.as_json()` метод и определите свой `json_encoder` класс:

```
class JSONEncoder(app.json_encoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if hasattr(o, 'as_json'):
            return o.as_json()
        else:
            return super().default(o)

app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
```

Comment: всё оказалось намного проще, дело в __repr__, которая возвращает str, и ей плевать на json.dumps. Поэтому решение:
1. Инициировать модуль как def module(self), вместо __repr__:
2. Можно, но не обязательно, передать как словарь:
results = [], далее добавить в него всё, а после
result = {"title%d" % (i+1): results[i] for i in range(len(results))}
return result
3. в файле views.py - вызывать как,
return jsonify(WeblancerSpider('keyword').module())

Comment: @leexxg: манипуляции с `__repr__` никак вам с `TypeError: Object of type 'Parser' is not JSON serializable` не помогут. Если у вас нет намерения возвращать всегда `{"error": ...}` для всех Parser() объектов, то следует его  JSON serializable сделать как в ответе указано.

Comment: repr, согласно документации должен возвращать строковое значение, и в случае использования json.dump, он не выдаёт ошибку, а заворачивает json-объект в str. А далее, данный обёрнутый json-объёкт поступает в jsonify, и поэтому ошибка выдаёт error внутри которого, вроде бы нормальный json-объект, но это всё то же строковое значение. Из-за этого была ошибка, указанные выше действия описаны уже после её устранения.

Comment: @leexxg это бред. Наличие `__repr__` не делает объект json serializable иначе все объекты по умолчанию работали бы с json.dumps. Чтобы убедиться, достаточно `repr(object())` вызвать (нет исключения) и сравнить с `json.dumps(object())` (ведёт к TypeError)